# Unable to prepare route[api/user] for serialisation. Uses Closure - Laravel

Tags: laravel

```
LogicException  : Unable to prepare route [api/user] for serialization. Uses Closure.

  at /var/www/html/dev_laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php:917
    913|      */
    914|     public function prepareForSerialization()
    915|     {
    916|         if ($this->action['uses'] instanceof Closure) {
  > 917|             throw new LogicException("Unable to prepare route [{$this->uri}] for serialization. Uses Closure.");
    918|         }
    919| 
    920|         $this->compileRoute();
    921| 

  Exception trace:

  1   Illuminate\Routing\Route::prepareForSerialization()
      /var/www/html/dev_laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/RouteCacheCommand.php:62

  2   Illuminate\Foundation\Console\RouteCacheCommand::handle()
      /var/www/html/dev_laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php:32
```

When i trying to run the laravel command

```
php artisan route:cache
```

I try to find out the solution but not get the correct solution. 
https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/22034

Is this laravel bug still or fixed the bug?

I have the code on web.php file

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
Route::resource('photos', 'PhotoController@index');
```

I'm Using Laravel 5.8. Just installed and migrated database. I'm beginner for laravel.

Can anyone let me know the correct solution?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not a bug. You can not use Closure based routes like that if you want to cache the routes. Direct any Closure based route to a Controller method instead and you will be fine. [You have one in `web.php` and the error is pointing out one in `api.php`]

The Closure based route you have in `web.php` could be replaced with:

```
Route::view('/', 'welcome');
```

This would direct it to a Controller that just handles returning view files.

The Closure based route in `api.php` should point to a Controller:

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('user', 'SomeController@user');
```

Consider any routes that come with the `laravel/laravel` project as being functional but are there for demonstration purposes.

> "Closure based routes cannot be cached. To use route caching, you must convert any Closure routes to controller classes."

[Laravel 5.8 - Docs - Controllers - Route Caching](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/controllers#route-caching)

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:

> AS OF LARAVEL 8.X YOU CAN ALSO CACHE CLOSURE BASED ROUTES

When you run the command `php artisan route:cache`

Laravel will cache all your routes and store it in **specified Cache Driver**

Now Comming to your Error Message:

As the error Message Clearly Says that

**Closure Routes can't be Cached**

And even the Laravel Docs says that [Route Caching](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/controllers#route-caching)

By Default Laravel Comes with Four routes files

And this will have 2 Closure based routes

Solution:

1. You can remove them if you no longer using that routes
2. Make a Controller and Move that to Controller

**LogicException  : Unable to prepare route [api/user]**

Which means that

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});
```

This Code in Your routes/api.php is causing the issue So

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')
->get('/user', 'SomeController@method');
```

Or you can remove that if not using that

Answer (score 0):

You could not use specific method when you use resource for the routing.

You can use

```
Route::resource('photos', 'PhotoController');
```

Or

```
Route::get('photos', 'PhotoController@index');
```