# After php artisan route:cache my routes stopped working because I have Closure based routes

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

I am working on a project on laravel, I have a few routes, I decided to php artisan route:cache and I got this error. My routes, almost of all them stopped working. When I click on a button for example, to update the user info, nothing happens anymore, how can I fix this or revert the changes I made with the routes cache, please help me

```
 Macintoshs-MacBook-Air:dpmanager macintoshhd$ php artisan route:cache
Route cache cleared!

   LogicException 

  Unable to prepare route [api/user] for serialization. Uses Closure.

  at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php:1081
    1077|      */
    1078|     public function prepareForSerialization()
    1079|     {
    1080|         if ($this->action['uses'] instanceof Closure) {
  > 1081|             throw new LogicException("Unable to prepare route [{$this->uri}] for serialization. Uses Closure.");
    1082|         }
    1083| 
    1084|         $this->compileRoute();
    1085| 

      +15 vendor frames 
  16  artisan:37
      
  
Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
```

I was searching for a solution, found this one, but I can't really implement it [Unable to prepare route[api/user] for serialisation. Uses Closure - Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58908205/unable-to-prepare-routeapi-user-for-serialisation-uses-closure-laravel)

```
Here is my routes code web.php

Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index'); 


Auth::routes();
Route::middleware('auth', 'isAdmin')->namespace('admin')->group(function(){
    Route::get('users', 'UsersController@index') -> name('admin.users');
    Route::get('admin/user/{id}', 'UsersController@getUser')->name('admin.user');
    Route::post('admin/users/store', 'UsersController@store')->name('admin.user.store');
    
    Route::put('admin/user/update', 'UsersController@update')-> name('admin.user.update');
});
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

Here is my api.php that I edited after I received the error

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('users', 'UsersController@index');
Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('admin/user/{id}', 'UsersController@getUser');
Route::middleware('auth:api')->post('admin/users/store', 'UsersController@store');
Route::middleware('auth:api')->put('admin/user/update', 'UsersController@update');
Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
```

EDITED

Here is the code for my two forms, my two blade templates

this is user.blade.php

```
@extends('admin.layouts.app')

@section('content')

<div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-3 p-3 pl-5">
    @component('admin.layouts.menus.sidebar')
        @endcomponent
    </div>
    @if(session('success'))
    <div class="alert-alert-success">
    {{session('success')}}
    </div>
    
    @endif
  <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-5 pl-2">
<div class="card">
<div class="card-header">
    Информация за пациента
    <span class="btn btn-sm float-right btn-primary" id="open-edit-details-modal">Редакция на информацията</span>
  </div>
    <div class="card-body">
       <h5>Име: {{ $user -> name}}</h5>
       <h5>Имейл: {{ $user -> email}}</h5>
       <h5>Тип: {{ $user -> role}}</h5>
       <h5>Активен: {{ $user -> isActive == 1 ? 'да' : 'не'}}</h5>

    </div>
   
    
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="card">
        
    </div>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>

{{-- /.row --}}
{{-- Modals --}}
      <div id="edit-details-modal" class="modal-cont">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 offset-sm-3" > 
        <div class="card mt-5">
             
            <div class="card-header">Променете информацията за: {{ $user -> name }} <span class="float-right" id="close-edit-details-modal" style="cursor:pointer;"><b>X</b></span>
            </div>
          <div class="card-body">
                {{-- Forms --}}
            <form action="{{ route('admin.user.update') }}" method="POST">
              @csrf
          @method('PUT')
                <input type="text" name="id" value="{{ $user -> id }}">
                <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name">Име на пациента</label>
                 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" value="{{$user -> name}}">
                    
                    
                </div>
              </form>
            
           
              
                <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email">Имейл на пациента</label>
                 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" value="{{$user -> email}}">
                </div>
             
              
        
              
                <div class="form-group">
                <label for="role">Роля на пациента</label>
                    <select name="role" class="form-control">
                         <option value="{{$user -> role}}">{{$user -> role}}</option>
                    <option value="user">User</option>
                        <option value="admin">Admin</option>
                    </select>
                 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" value="{{$user -> role}}">
                </div>
            
              
              
            
                <div class="form-group">
                <label for="isActive">Активност</label>
                    <select name="isActive" class="form-control">
                        
                        {{--
               @if ($user -> isActive == 1)
                        <option value="1">да</option>
                         <option value="0">не</option>
                        @else
                       <option value="0">не</option>
                       <option value="1">да</option>
                        @endif
                        --}}
                        <option value="1" {{$user->isActive == 1 ? 'default' : ''}}>да</option>
                          <option value="0" {{$user->isActive == 0 ? 'default' : '' }}> не</option>
                    </select>
                    
            
                </div>
             
                           <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn" value="Промяна на информацията">
                           
           
              
                 {{-- End of forms --}}
            </div>
          </div>
          </div>
      </div>
      </div> 
      @endsection

@push('admin.layouts.scripts.scripts')
<script src="{{ asset('js/admin/user.js')}}"></script>

@endpush
@push('admin.layouts.styles')
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/admin/user.css')}}" />

@endpush
```

and this is add_user.blade.php

```
<form action="{{route('admin.user.store')}}" method="POST" id="new-user-form" class="px-5 py-4">
@csrf
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Име на пациент:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control {{$errors ->has('name') ? 'is-invalid' : ''}}" name="name">
        @if($errors->has('name'))
        <div class="invalid-feedback">
        {{$errors -> first('name')}}
        </div>
        @endif
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="email">Имейл на пациента</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control {{$errors ->has('email') ? 'is-invalid' : ''}}" name="email">
         @if($errors->has('email'))
        <div class="invalid-feedback">
        {{$errors -> first('email')}}
        </div>
        @endif
    </div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="role" >Каква ще е неговата роля</label>
    <select name="role" class="form-control {{$errors ->has('role') ? 'is-invalid' : ''}}">
    <option value="user" default>Пациент</option>
    <option value="admin">Фото студио</option>
    </select>
    </div>
</form>
 <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" id="show-new-user-form">Добави нов пациент</button>
```

Comment: Hello, I removed all the Closures, php artisan route:cache was successful without any errors, then I checked php artisan route:list, there were no closures, but most of my routes still do not work, I click the button and nothing happens... help me please

Comment: if you clear the route cache, do the routes work?

Comment: Do you get any error? If so, then let us know.  Clear your route and try `php artisan route:clear`

Comment: Hello, I was clearing the cache multiple times, I actually don’t receive any errors, but when I try to add a new user to the database for example, when I click on the button after filling the inputs, nothing happens, no errors or anything

Comment: Which routes listed above don't work? or, which ones do work?

Comment: @TysonL. - these ones do not work: 
Route::post('admin/users/store', 'UsersController@store')->name('admin.user.store');
Route::put('admin/user/update', 'UsersController@update')->name('admin.user.update');

Comment: @TysonL. - these ones do not work: Route::post('admin/users/store', 'UsersController@store')->name('admin.user.store'); Route::put('admin/user/update', 'UsersController@update')->name('admin.user.update');

The others work.

Comment: And when you say it does nothing, do you mean it takes you to an empty page? or it just stays on the same page? It may also be helpful to show us the two methods in your UsersController Class along with the namespace you're using

Comment: It stays on the same page, no action happens, I will show you the two methods in the UsersController Class and the namespaces

Answer (score 1):

Would you be able to show us the code used in your blade template so we can see the form parameters?

If you're using ajax to make an API call and you're trying to access the PUT route, then you need to pass a parameter into your request data object on the client side. For example, if I was using Axios I would run my query like this:

```
axios.post('/this/is/my/route', {
    _method: 'PUT',
    other: 'parameters',
    go: 'here'
}).then(response => {
//Do something with the response
})
```

All requests made to the server are picked up as either GET or POST requests. The additional "_method: 'PUT'" parameter will tell laravel that it needs to access the PUT route.

If you're not making the request via ajax when submitting the form, then make sure that you have added the @method('PUT') in your form.

Comment: Another possible reason is that you are missing the csrf token in your api call. If that's the case though, none of your other post requests would work.

Comment: Hello, edited my question, you can now see the code of the blade templates for add_user and user.blade

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it, the problem was in the Validation

I checked for errors again, the problem was that on one of the Routes, the e-mail was actually not required, something like that, I fixed it in the below code, also, the name attribute for the html of the  was name="name" instead of name="email", it could not run, did dd($request) too and checked it out, also about the other Route, where I am adding a user, the problem is that now somehow my button was actually not running the form, but was doing a javascript event on click, I added one more into the form itself, that a type="submit" and fixed it

```
public function update(Request $request){
   
        $request -> validate([
             'id' => 'required', 
            'name' => 'required',
           'email' => 'required|unique:users,email',
           'role'=>'required',
            'isActive' => 'required',
       
        ]);
        $user = User::find($request -> id);
        
        $user -> name = $request -> name;
        $user -> email = $request -> email;
        $user -> role = $request -> role;
        $user -> isActive = $request -> isActive;
        
        $user -> save();
        
        return redirect('admin/user/' . $user->id)-> with('success', 'Успешно променени детайли');
        
    }
}
```